# transfering json url from form 1 to form 2

Tags: c#, json

I've got two forms and I want to use the json url and the data from the first form to the second form.

form 1 : 
this is where i open the second form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://dev.ibeaconlivinglab.com:1881/companybyuuid?uuid="+textBox1.Text);
        List<details> detailsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<details>>(json);

        foreach (details dets in detailsList)
        {

            if (textBox1.Text == dets.uuid)
            {

                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = false;

                Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
                secondForm.Show();

            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Company not found.");

            }
        }
    }
```

second form;

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - Width,
        Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - Height);

        Label namelabel = new Label();
        namelabel.Location = new Point(13, 30);

        foreach (details dets in detailsList)
        {

            namelabel.Text = dets.id;
            this.Controls.Add(namelabel);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor on Form2. You can either pass in the json, the details object or the individual details item (in your loop).For example, to pass the json, use the snippet below. Add additional parameters for the url etc. For the url you may want to consider using [AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) to have it available throughout your application.

```
Form2 secondForm = new Form2(json, jsonUrl);
```

and in Form2, change the constructor to the following.

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private string json = "";
        private string jsonUrl = "";

        public Form2(string jsonPassedId, string jsonUrlPassedIn)
        {
            json = jsonPassedId;
            jsonUrl = jsonUrlPassedIn;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Use json and json URL here or in the constructor as required. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to use the url to the second form.

Comment: See edited answer. Just pass across what you need by changing the constructor method signature.

Comment: what about the jsonText?

Comment: That is your json - I have modified the sample.   Form2 secondForm = new Form2(json, jsonUrl);